# Firebase .limit() function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a long list of entries that are pushed into Firebase. I am trying to conduct a query on them:

```
firebase.database().ref('/Ocean/').orderByChild(child).equalTo(search).once('value').then((snapshot) => { 
  ... Do Stuff
})
```

The above line works, however I am now trying to 
a) limit the original database before it gets ordered (say to 1000) and 
b) limit the results of the query to show only 25 results.

For part a) I have tried inserting `.limit(1000)` into the above line with no success:

> firebase.default.database(...).ref(...).limit is not a function.

Am I misunderstanding how to use .limit()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`limit()` should be used after `equal()`:

```
firebase.database().ref('/Ocean/').orderByChild(child).limitToLast(1000).once
```

Comment: I have a question about this. So in the example you give, will Firebase order and then limit the results? I would like it to limit before ordering. Would .ref().limitToLast().orderByChild()... achieve this? Also I tried to integrate the .limit after this, but I still get the same error regarding .limit(): firebase.database().ref('/Ocean/').limitToLast(1000000).orderByChild(child).equalTo(search).limit(25).once('value').then((snapshot) => {})

Comment: There is no `.limit` I don't know what docs you are checking. Also `limitToLast` should be after `orderByChild`

Comment: Ok, but will this limit before or after ordering?

Comment: after ordering.

Comment: Ok, but I need this before ordering, so should the limitToLast be before the orderByChild?